Visited chat info page buttons now have a dark background color, making them hard to read
I recall that the background color used to be white, but the visited chat info page buttons now have a fairly dark blue or purple type background color that makes them hard for me to read, as shown below. Note the screenshot is from 2024 Mathematics Stack Exchange Moderator Election Chat, but it's also the same with other chat rooms, e.g., Cured, where I've used (i.e., "visited") the "join this room" and "view transcript" chat info buttons.

I suspect this is related to After the visited links color change, I can’t easily see the badges I've earned as the background color there appears to be the same. This is also because both these issues appeared around when this answer was just posted to Make visited post titles a more distinct color on Meta.SE indicating that such a colour change has been made.

Note the above problem described above only occurred for certain chat info pages. Others, like SO Close Vote Reviewers, didn't have this issue:

This appears to be related to the layout and/or color scheme used for the particular chat room.

Probably caused by the color changes described in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/402147/196432

@MartinR Thanks for letting me know. Since you've already pointed out this issue in your comment there, I'll delete this question shortly.

I don't think you should delete this. A proper bug report is better than a comment.

@MartinR Thanks for your feedback. In that case, I'll won't delete this question. I'll also post a comment on your linked answer indicating that this bug report is here.

As indicated by the status-completed question status, this has been fixed. The 2024 Mathematics Stack Exchange Moderator Election Chat info page buttons now look like this:

In particular, the "join this room" and "view transcript" buttons I've clicked (i.e., "visited") use white text, as I recall they used to previously.
